# Particularly interesting is

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

Is it grammatically correct to begin a sentence with:

Particularly interesting is...

Thanks in advance

Comment: It depends how you finish it.

Comment: Particularly interesting is general relativity because....

Comment: This is just a personal style preference, but I would say 'General relativity is of particular interest because...'. It sounds better to me, but this is entirely subjective.

Comment: @GrahamNicol - much better.

Answer (score 1):

I can see no reason not to use it. Certainly it has been used in many published works:

[Google ngram: particularly interesting is](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=particularly%20interesting%20is&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cparticularly%20interesting%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BParticularly%20interesting%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bparticularly%20interesting%20is%3B%2Cc0)

[image]